# Can anyone tell me how to draw curved lines from item to item in javascript for arbitrary angles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

Just for context, I'm using html5, css, and jquery.

I'd like to be able to draw curved lines with arrowheads between two elements on a web page.  I've nearly got it, but just can't wrap my head around the maths to draw the arrow heads.  Could just be the manipulation of the canvas widget that's getting me.

Here's the javascript I'm using at the minute.  It certainly feels the long way around, but it seems to get the job done except for those pesky arrowheads.

The 'influence' variable is to vary the lines a bit so that if there are multiple lines they will show one behind the other.

```
  var start = $('#firstobject');
  var last = $('#lastobject');
  var stpos = start.position();
  var lastpos = last.position();
  var influence = Math.random*20+5;
  var maxx = Math.max(stpos.left,lastpos.left);
  var minx = Math.min(stpos.left,lastpos.left);
  var maxy = Math.max(stpos.top,lastpos.top);
  var miny = Math.min(stpos.top,lastpos.top);
  var w = maxx - minx;
  var h = maxy - miny;
  var cname = "samplename";
  var cpad = 30;
  var cstr = "<canvas id='"+cname+"' class='huntgroupcanvas' style='z-index:2;position:absolute;left:"+(0+minx-cpad)+"px;top:"+(0+miny-cpad)+"px;' id='"+cname+"' width="+(2*cpad+w)+" height="+(2*cpad+h)+"></canvas>"
  start.before(cstr);
  var canvas = document.getElementById(cname);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var dx = stpos.left - lastpos.left;
  var dy = stpos.top - lastpos.top;
  var dir = dy/dx;
  var sx,sy,ex,ey;
  if (dir<0) {
    ex=w+cpad;
    ey=cpad;
    sx=cpad;
    sy=h+cpad;
  } else {
    ex=w+cpad;
    ey=h+cpad;
    sx=cpad;
    sy=cpad;
  }

  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(sx,sy);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(((w/2)-(h/2))+cpad-influence,((h/2)-(w/2))+cpad,ex,ey);
  ctx.stroke();
  if (st==i-1) {
    first=0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    if (dx<0) {
      ctx.arc(sx,sy,6,0,Math.PI*2,0);
    } else {
      ctx.arc(ex,ey,6,0,Math.PI*2,0);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }

 /* Here's where I've been trying to draw the arrowheads.
  * I know that I can get the slope of the line like so:
    var m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
  * I know I can get the angle in radians as
    var angle=Math.atan(m);
  * I'm trying to use rotation to draw the arrowhead
 */
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      angle = Math.atan(dir);
      if (dx<0) {
        sx=ex;
        sy=ey;
        angle = Math.atan(-dir);
      }
      ctx.moveTo(sx,sy);
      ctx.translate(sx,sy);
      ctx.rotate(angle - 0.05);
      ctx.lineTo(20,0);
      ctx.rotate(angle + 0.05);
      ctx.lineTo(20,0);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Oops, to work with IE8 + excanvas, you need this for canvas creation:

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$(canvas).css({'z-index':2,'position':'absolute','left':(0+minx-cpad)+"px",'top':(0+miny-cpad)+"px"});
$(canvas).attr('name',cname).attr('class','huntgroupcanvas').attr('width',(2*cpad+w)).attr('height',(2*cpad+h)).insertBefore(start);
if($.browser.msie) canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of code to read, but it would seem that you are messing up your trigonometry when generating the angle of the arrowhead. Take a look at the atan2 function, it takes a 2D vector and converts it to it's angle. So you would want to use `angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx)`

Comment: Thanks, but...the bit that needs work is at the bottom.  All the code above the comment is for (painful, over-wordy, scare newbies off, over the top) context.  The broken bit is after getting the angle.

Comment: Well, your angle finding is clearly broken as well, you will only ever find numbers in the ]-π/2; π/2[ range. As for the code after that, I have no idea how that would make an arrow, I don't know where to begin correcting it, isn't it just supposed to draw two straight lines?

Comment: Well, to be honest I don't know (which is why I'm posting this to you all).  This web page does something quite similar to draw a star: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing  (similar meaning it works and mine obviously doesn't.)